# App Store Connect. Cant add new version there is no blue plus button appearing. Anyone know why this could be?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVUPS.png)

App store connect,

I cant seem to add any new versions to my app. I have all the permissions i need but still no Blue plus button appear beside the "iOS App"

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me is to resize the browser window. With increasing the width of the window the "+"-Button appears.